# how to get each hexadecimal value present in the text box into an array?

Tags: vb.net

In my application, the users may need to add hexadecimals in the textbox during run time and I would like to get each hexadecimal value in an array by removing the spaces if there are any.

For example, the data in the textbox is "ff 00 ff 1a ff 00". I could able to get each hexadecimal as an array with the help of split. But, now I am trying to remove all the spaces as some users may enter the hexadecimals without giving the space. For example, the user my enter as "ff 00 ff1a ff 00". So, in this case the third array contains "ff1a", which is not true. I know how to remove the spaces, but  cannot able to figure  out the way to get each hexadecimal into an array.

```
'Used to split the strings based on the spaces, which is not useful
 'Dim extraData As String() = Split(TextBox8.Text, " ")

'Used to remove the spaces
Dim myString = TextBox8.Text.Replace(" ", "")
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by each hex value? Like in "ff 00 a1" - there are 3 values - ff, 00 and a1?

Comment: Possible dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: @roryap This is a completely different question.

Comment: @FarhanAnam -- Nope.  If you remove all spaces and pipe that through the algorithm in that answer, you should be all set.

Comment: @FarhanAnam, Yes hex value is something like that.

Comment: I don't think that link is the duplicate of my question as I am not trying to convert any string to byte or byte to string. @roryap.

Comment: I've posted an answer check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim list As New List(Of String) 
input = input.Replace(" ", "")
For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1 Step 2
    list.Add(input.Substring(i, 2))
Next
Dim array = list.ToArray()
```

**Note - The length of the input (after removing spaces) must be even. Otherwise, it may throw an exception.**

Answer (score 0):

If I convert the method from C# to VB.NET given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/2704659):

```
Public Function StringToByteArray(hex As [String]) As Byte()
    Dim NumberChars As Integer = hex.Length
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(NumberChars / 2 - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To NumberChars - 1 Step 2
        bytes(i / 2) = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)
    Next
    Return bytes
End Function
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
StringToByteArray(YourInputString.Replace(" ", ""))
```

This will return an array of bytes and will also validate the input because it will thrown an exception if invalid characters are used in the input (like non-hex characters).

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have accepted an answer, however, I'd like to suggest another alternative.  I'm assuming, based on the context of your question and the example that you provided, that your intention is to parse a list of bytes, where each byte is represented by a two digit hexadecimal value.

If you use regex to find your matches, it will be more powerful.  For instance, you can easily ignore all white-space characters (e.g. tabs, new-lines) and you can easily validate the data to make sure that only properly formatted bytes are in the string (i.e. `00` - `FF`).  For instance, you could do something like this:

```
Dim bytes As New List(Of String)()
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "^\s*((?<byte>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})\s*)*$")
If m.Success Then
    Dim g As Group = m.Groups("byte")
    If g.Success Then
        For Each c As Capture In g.Captures
            bytes.Add(c.Value)
        Next
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input is not properly formatted")
End If
```

However, if the idea is to parse the actual byte values, you can do so using `Byte.Parse`, like this:

```
Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)()
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "^\s*((?<byte>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})\s*)*$")
If m.Success Then
    Dim g As Group = m.Groups("byte")
    If g.Success Then
        For Each c As Capture In g.Captures
            bytes.Add(Byte.Parse(c.Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
        Next
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input is not properly formatted")
End If
```

Both of those examples use the same regex pattern to find all of the hexadecimal bytes in the string.  The pattern it uses is:

```
^\s*((?<byte>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})\s*)*$
```

Here's the meaning of the regex pattern:

- `$` - The match must start at the beginning of the string (i.e. no invalid text can come before the bytes)
- `\s*` - Any number of white-space characters can come before the first byte

  - `\s` - Any white-space character
  - `*` - Zero or more times
- `((?<byte>[a-fA-F0-9]{2})\s*)*` - Any number of bytes, each separated by any number of white-space characters

  - `(` - Begins the group so that we can later apply a [kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) to the whole group (which means the whole group can repeat any number of times)
  - `(?<byte>` - Begins another, inner group which is named `"byte"`.  It is given a name so that we can easily reference the values captured by the group in the VB code.
  - `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}` - A two-digit hexadecimal byte (i.e. `00` - `FF`)
  - `[a-fA-F0-9]` - Any character between `a` and `f` or between `A` and `F` or between `0` and `9`
  - `{2}` - There must be exactly two characters matching that specification
  - `)` - Ends the group named `"byte"`.  Notice that this named-group only captures the two actual hexadecimal digits.  It does not capture any of the white-space between the bytes.
  - `\s*` - There can be any number of white-space characters after a byte
  - `)` - The ends outer group which includes a byte and all of the white-space that comes after it
  - `*` - The aforementioned kleene star meaning that the outer-group can repeat any number of times
- `$` - The match must end at the ending of the string (i.e. no invalid text can come after the bytes)